# How to download data created server-side with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, web, download

I want to retrieve some data from my REST API in Node to the user directly downloaded in json file when he clicks a link.

I tried some stuff using Blop, but it is not working in my case I don't understand why...

#### HTML

```
<div class='wrapper_align_vertical'>
        <a class='shortCut' id='extract'>Extract</a>
    </div>
```

#### JS (sample that is working)

Viewed this example on internet and worked well with sample data.

```
document.getElementById('extract').onclick = function(event){
    var data = { a: 1, b: "hello" }
    var json = JSON.stringify(data)
    var blob = new Blob([json], {type: "octet/stream"})
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)

    this.href = url
    this.target = '_blank'

    // target filename
    this.download = 'data.json'
}
```

But in my case I am calling API to gather data from database before creating the blop.

#### How I am getting data

I am calling the API with ajax request.

```
function getFromDB(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/extract',
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "x-access-token" : getCookie('token')
            },
            success: function(data){
                if(data.success == 'true'){
                    resolve(data)
                } else{
                    reject('Promise getFromDB failed !')
                }
           }
        })
    })
}
```

**EDIT** : I added error verification in case the promise fail, and it is not the case unfortunately ! Moreover I printed the data in the console and everything seems fine, it is complete... Resolve data is sending back the right json object.

#### What return the route /api/extract

The route get data from DB.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){

    var query = 'SELECT ...'

    connection.query(query, function(err, rows){
        var result = []
        if(!err){
            for(label in rows){
                result.push(rows[label].path)
            }
            res.json({
                success: true,
                data:{
                    quantity : rows.length,
                    image: result
                }
            })
        }else{
            res.json({
                success: false,
                message: 'Failure while extracting tags from database !'
            })
        }
    })
})
```

#### What I want to do

But it is absolutely not working, maybe I am missing something ?

```
document.getElementById('extract').onclick = function(event){

    getFromDB()
    .then(function(data){
        var json = JSON.stringify(data)
        var blob = new Blob([json], {type: "octet/stream"})
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)

        this.href = url
        this.target = '_blank'

        this.download = 'data.json'
    }, function(err){
        // Promise failed
        console.log(err)
    })

}
```

#### More informations

I saw something else that might help debugging... While using the API with Postman I am getting header 200 :

```
GET /api/extract 200 5.484 ms - 375
```

BUT ! When it's through the ajax call, I get code 304 :

```
GET /api/extract 304 6.339 ms - -
```

If you have any advice or suggestion I'll appreciate, thank you !

Comment: try to add `error` handler to `$.ajax` call and react by rejecting the promise `reject(err)`. Print error into the console. In case of error by loading data via Ajax is the error lost otherwise...

Comment: @Barney I added error handling in my question, but it is not the problem, the data returning are 100% correct and the promise succeed. I can log the data in the .then() and it is still correct and complete. I also added information about returning code, it is different when I call the ajax than with my regular Postman...... Don't know what it means.